# Excel Averages (running tally)

Tags: vba, excel, time, average

I'm new here and new to using computer languages, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Created my first Excel spreadsheet using Excel 2010 and I learned how to trick it out with all kinds of efficiency-enhancing effects. It's a study log detailing how much time I spend in hours:minutes using various study tools. A link to the image (sorry, I don't have reputation enough yet to include the image here): https://www.flickr.com/photos/32200016@N02/15835875961/lightbox/

A key below with details as to the problem I'd like to solve.

---

***Key:*** 
The following are highlighted in the image with **purple** arrows.

__

***A** is today's date, page automatically goes here and highlights in red when the workbook is opened.

***B** This entire green bar is a running tally of how much time I've spent on each tool that week. THIS IS FOR EACH INDIVIDUAL TOOL.

Column "H" tells me how much I've studied that day, adding up the times for all tools. If it has a red "0:00" then either I did nothing that day or that day has yet to arrive.

***C** - ***THE PROBLEM*** - This is the weekly average. It basically adds up all of "Column H" for that week. The cursor is on it so you can see the formula I'm using above in the formula bar. The formula is "=AVERAGE(H50:H56)". Unfortunately, this includes all of the red "*0:00*"s that make up the rest of the week. While this formula is great for seeing my mean study time at the END of the week, I was hoping to program it so that it automatically gives me the mean/average from the beginning of the week (H50) to the current date (H54) and adjusts it with every day that passes so that I know where I stand whenever I look at it. Currently, it tells me that my average study time is 0h:44m:17s, which is considerably lowered due to the inclusion of those "00:00"s.

***D** This is the total number of hours completed this week. Again, it's a running tally, but I don't need to change anything here.

***E** - (Dark Green Cell) This is the average for the month. I'd essentially like to do here what I wish to do with ***C**. The formula just uses the totals for all of the "H" Column from the first of the month down to the last of the month. I'd like it to give me the monthly average as I go without including any remaining future dates within the same month.

---

Comment: How about `=AVERAGEIF(A50:A56,"<="&TODAY(),H50:H56)` or `=AVERAGEIFS(H50:H56, A50:A56,"<="&TODAY(), H50:H56, ">"&0)`? [AVERAGEIF function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/averageif-function-HA010047433.aspx) [AVERAGEIFS function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/averageifs-function-HA010047493.aspx)

Comment: Yes, thank you, I think your first suggestion may have done the trick. I calculated it and it seems to be correct. I notice your reply does not appear as an answer. How did you arrive at your conclusion? It would really help me if I could understand the brass tacks.

Comment: Now how would I translate this over to the green bar (month)? I tried adding in all the cells, but it tells me there's too many much info for this function. Obviously it involves a larger set of data.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=SUM(H50:H56)/COUNTIF(H50:H56,"<>0")
```

Comment: Does this give me an average or a sum?